# arcpy.SetParameterAsText fails in Python script tool

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool, parameters

I am trying to create a derived output parameter for a Python script tool so that the output will show in a model (I want to use the output folder as an input for another tool). I want this output to be a folder that is the same as an input folder after geoprocessing has put the results (outShapeFiles) into that folder. Essentially, I have 4 initial parameters, one of which is the `outFolder = sys.argv[4]`. At the end of the code, I set `outFolder = arcpy.SetParameterAsText(5, "Output Features"). When I run it, everything works but the last part (the outShapefiles are created and put into the outFolder). I get this error message: "RuntimeError: Object: Error in setting parameter as text." Here is the code. Can you see how I can resolve this error so that my output parameter can be viable in a model? Note how I set outFolder at the end.

```
input_FC = sys.argv[1]
inField = sys.argv[2]
theFName = sys.argv[3]
outFolder = sys.argv[4] #Set as an input parameter in the script tool

script = sys.argv[0]
msg = "\nRunning: ... {}".format(script)
arcpy.AddMessage(msg)

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
...

...
aMax = 1
for aVal in valueList:
  aMax = max(aMax, len(str(aVal)))
for aVal in valueList:
  if (str(aVal).isdigit()) and (not inType == "String"):
    fs = '"' + "%" + str(aMax) + "." + str(aMax) + 'i"'
    aSuffix = fs % aVal
    aVal = str(aVal)
  elif inType == "Double" and inScale == 0:
    aSuffix = str(aVal).replace(".0","")  ###### 
    aVal = str(aVal).replace(".0","")
  else:
    aSuffix = str(aVal) 
    aVal = str(aVal)
  try:
    aSuffix = aSuffix.replace(" ","_")  #replace garbage in output files
    aSuffix = aSuffix.replace('"',"")
    aSuffix = aSuffix.replace("/","")
    aSuffix = aSuffix.replace("-","")
    outName = theFName + aSuffix + ".shp"
    outShapeFile = outFolder + "/" + outName
    outShapeFile = outShapeFile.replace("\\","/")
    # 
    #Create a query and produce the file
    if (not aVal.isdigit()) or (inType == "String"):
      aVal = "'" + aVal + "'"
    whereClause = "%s = %s" % (inField, aVal)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input_FC, "TempLayer", whereClause)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("TempLayer",outShapeFile)
    arcpy.AddMessage("Output and query: " + outShapeFile + "  " + 
    whereClause)
  except:
    whereClause = "%s = %s" % (inField, aVal)
    arcpy.AddMessage("Output and query: " + outShapeFile + "  " + 
    whereClause + " did not work ")

arcpy.SetParameterAsText(5, outFolder) #This is where I try to 
make outFolder an output parameter. I have set it to derived from the input "outFolder".

arcpy.AddMessage("\n  Processing complete" + "\n")
del arcpy
```

Comment: In your question, you state that you are setting: "outFolder = arcpy.SetParameterAsText(5, "Output Features")", but your code shows differently: outFolder = arcpy.SetParameterAsText(6, "Output").

Comment: Sorry, I had changed it and run it in a test, thinking that `sys.argv` uses an index starting with zero, so technically, counting `sys.argv[0]`, outFolder as an output would be the 6th parameter defined. Basically, I got the same error. I am confused on this point since I am trying to use `sys.argv` and `arcpy.SetParametersAsText` in the same script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the answer to this question is simple. I first changed my primary input parameters to use arcpy.GetParameterAsText.

```
 input_FC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
 inField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
 theFName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
 outFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
 script = sys.argv[0]
```

At the bottom, I added my ouput parameter, set to equal `outFolder` (I probably could have simplified this).

```
 output = outFolder
 arcpy.SetParameterAsText(4, output)
```

Now, at the top, notice that arcpy.GetParameterAsText starts its index at 0, not 1. This was the crux of my problem before. Once I set my final output parameter to 4, it was fine. I then set it as the last item in my parameter settings as Derived (automatically as an output) and it worked fine. 
[image]

The main lesson here is to always start the index off at 0, not 1. Hope this helps anyone with a similar problem.